# C - Finding the index of the largest item in 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

```
       #include <stdio.h>

       int main () {

           int a[5][2] = { {0,0}, {1,2}, {2,4}, {3,6},{4,8}};
           int i, j;

           for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
               for ( j = 0; j < 2; j++ ) {
                   printf("a[%d][%d] = %d\n", i,j, a[i][j] );
               }
           }
           return 0;
       }
```

So I have this code so far, it writes every single element on the screen, but I would also like to write the highest number and its index. I'm only a beginner, so I'd like to ask your opinion.

Comment: What did you try? Your code does nothing but printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
   int main ( void )
```

As for the searching of the maximum element then the approach is simple. At first it is supposed that the maximum element is the first element of the array. Then all other elements of the array are compared with this maximum and if some element is greater than the maximum then it becomes the maximum.

For example

```
   #include <stdio.h>

   #define M 5
   #define N 2

   int main ( void ) 
   {
       int a[M][N] = 
       { 
           { 0, 0 }, { 1, 2 }, { 2, 4 }, { 3, 6 }, { 4, 8 } 
       };

       int i, j;
       int max_i, max_j;

       for ( i = 0; i < M; i++ ) 
       {
           for ( j = 0; j < N; j++ ) 
           {
               printf("a[%d][%d] = %d\n", i,j, a[i][j] );
           }
       }

       max_i = 0;
       max_j = 0;

       for ( i = 0; i < M; i++ ) 
       {
           for ( j = 0; j < N; j++ ) 
           {
               if ( a[max_i][max_j] < a[i][j] )
               {
                   max_i = i;
                   max_j = j;
               }  
           }
       }

       printf( "The maximum value is %d at row %d and column %d\n", 
               a[max_i][max_j], max_i, max_j );

       return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

It is nice to get effort (and code) with a question. Good job. All you need to do is compare each array value and save the largest as `max`. Note, whenever searching for a *maximum* value, it is good practice to initialize your `max` value as the *minimum* for that storage type ('int') in this case. So initializing to `INT_MIN` insures that any value (even a large negative one if all your values are negative) will be larger than the initial value. To capture the indexes where the maximum value occurs, simply save the index values for `i`, `j` each time you save a `max` value and you will have captured the indexes where the maximum value occurrs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main () {

    int a[][2] = {{0,0}, {1,2}, {2,4}, {3,6},{4,8}};
    int maxrow = -1, maxcol = -1;
    int nrows = sizeof a/sizeof *a;
    int i, j, max = INT_MIN;

    for (i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++ ) {
            printf("a[%d][%d] = %d\n", i,j, a[i][j] );

            /* find largess value */
            if (a[i][j] > max) {
                max = a[i][j];
                maxrow = i;
                maxcol = j;
            }
        }
    }

    printf ("\n maximum value at 'a[%d][%d]' : %d\n\n", 
            maxrow, maxcol, max);

    return 0;
}
```

**Compile**

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -O3 -o bin/array_max array_max.c
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/array_max
a[0][0] = 0
a[0][1] = 0
a[1][0] = 1
a[1][1] = 2
a[2][0] = 2
a[2][1] = 4
a[3][0] = 3
a[3][1] = 6
a[4][0] = 4
a[4][1] = 8

 maximum value at 'a[4][1]' : 8
```

Comment: *I would also like to write the highest number and its index*

Comment: No problem hold on and I'll update `:)`

Answer (score -1):

you can use the following code:

```
int max,pi,pj;
max = –2147483648;
for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
    for(j=0; j<2; j++) {
        if(a[i][j] > max) {
            max = a[i][j];
            pi = i;
            pj = j;
        }
    }
}
```